# What does the "cancel" icon in the volume prompt mean?

Tags: macos, audio

I connected my earphone and when I tried to change the volume, I got a prompt like

[image]

Except that there was a small "cancel" icon in it (like [this](https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cosmo-symbols/40/cancel_1-512.png)). I could not change the volume. I had to unplug and plug again the earphone.

What does that ***mean***?

OSX Yosemite. Macbook Pro Retina Display, Mid 2014 model.

Comment: Does the audio start to work after you unplug and plug the earphone back in? Also, do you have any other devices such as a Thunderbolt or HDMI monitor plugged into your computer? Lastly, Go to Apple Menu -> About This Mac -> System Report -> Audio. Do you have any devices (such as Intel High Definition Audio) listed for driving sound?

Comment: Yes, it starts to work after re-plugging it. No, I don't have other such devices. I do see an `Intel High Definition Audio` under System Report, yes.

Comment: That shows up when system thinks the internal volume has been replaced with the external (the device) volume control.

Comment: @Buscar웃 well, that would be true, yes. But why would it block me from changing the volume? It is until I re-plug it that it will finally let me change it.

Comment: good question, as said, it gets confused thinking the external device is the master volume control. What kind of plug are you using (the Apple kind?)

Comment: @Buscar웃 This time it happened with Samsung ones. In the past, I think I've had the same issue with Mavericks while using Apple earphones.

Comment: Your Audio Plug might be wacky, try to clean it. (blow out or vacuum, no liquids or metal objects.

Comment: What would be interesting to know is when it does not work, look in the About this Mac Audio, for what is it reporting you have plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you cannot change the volume for the selected output device. For example, if you connect your mac to a TV using a HDMI cord, you will not be able to control the TV's volume with your mac. You'll have to use the TV's remote instead.

This shouldn't ever happen when you connect something into the headphone jack though. Perhaps you have a faulty set of headphones?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you cannot control volume for that output device.

Usually I solve this issue going into sound preference panel and changing the output device to speakers and back to headphones. 
Now your volume control should work as expected.